# How can I decompressed and read a file which is inside server?

Tags: php, server, readfile

I have 3 json.gz files in a remote server. These 3 files need to be decompressed,read and data should be added in a DB all with PHP. I have no problems doing this if the script is in my pc, but this need to be done while inside the server, as I'm going to set a cron with the script to be executed everyday. 
How can I do it?
Please any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You have access to the remote server?

Comment: Yes I have, I will set the cron as root.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a linux command in php by surrounding it with the backtick operator, so you could do something like this.

```
// gunzip the file
$cmd = `gunzip /path/to/compressed_file.json.gz`;
// read the file content 
$json = file_get_contents("/path/to/compressed_file.json");
// insert the data if it was read correctly
if($json){
    array($json); // trying to indicate here that you would use this value in a prepared statement in either pdo or mysqli
    $sql = "insert into table_name (datafield) values (?);"
}
```

You will need to sort out the sql or give us more info about the database

When you run `gunzip` it will decompress the file in place and remove the .gz extension.